# Go through array from 1-10 and find next missing number?

Tags: php, arrays

Say i have the following array: `1,2,3,6,8`

I need to find that the next missing number is 4

What is the easiest and quickest way to perform this ?

Comment: Is array always sorted?

Comment: You're getting answers, but something like this, you really should try and figure out how to do before you ask the question if only for the exercise of testing your coding skills.

Comment: What about 5 and 7, or are those numbers irrelevant?

Answer (score 6):

```
$missing = array_diff(range(min($myArray), max($myArray)), $myArray);
$nextMissing = (!empty($missing)) ? array_shift($missing) : max($myArray) + 1;
```

Comment: Works beautifully, as per your edit. +1

Comment: Note that it's a bit painful if `$myArray` is `[1,9999999]` though

Answer (score 0):

Iterating the array and checking [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) should do it.

```
$missing = null;

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    if (!in_array($i, $myArray)) {
        $missing = $i;
        break;
    }
}

if (!is_null($missing)) {
    // hit
}
```

Comment: So, the first one found missing would be zero?

Comment: Good catch, tweaked to start at 1. If the downvote was yours for that, that's a bit picky :P If it was someone else, fair enough

Comment: wasn't my downvote. but the OP changed his question as well, so not sure if your answer remains relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The Question is worded poorly but from my understanding you have `1,2,3` and then you need to check that next value should be 4

```
$prev = array[0];
for($i = 1; $i < count(array); $i++){
   if(array[$i] != prev+1) return (prev+1) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this (if the array is **sorted**):

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 6, 8);
$size = count($array);
$missing = 0;
$firstval = $array[0];

for ($i = 0; $i < $size; ++$i) {
    if ($firstval++ != $array[$i]) {
        $missing = $firstval - 1;
        break;
    }
}

if ($missing != 0) echo $missing.' is missing'.PHP_EOL;
```

Which gives:

`4 is missing`